# Culture Not Being Set In App

Tags: c#, wpf, globalization, cultureinfo

I'm working on a WPF / C# app that needs to be culturally aware for globalization.  I already have resource files and a bindable translation manager that is all working as expected.

At the moment I'm doing this:

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = _currentlyConfiguredUiCulture;
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = _currentlyConfiguredUiCulture;
```

This is all wired up in the UI like this:

```
TranslationManager.Instance.LanguageChanged += TranslationManager_LanguageChanged;

private void TranslationManager_LanguageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = TranslationManager.Instance.CurrentLanguage;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = TranslationManager.Instance.CurrentLanguage;
}
```

This all works sweet!

The problem is when the app is started my machine locale is "en-GB" and this is correctly set using the code shown above.  However, when I hit some code I have in an IValueConverter class dealing with dates:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        return DateTime.Parse(value.ToString(), culture);
    }

    return null;
}
```

The culture property here is always "en-US" ... how on earth is this occurring?  How do I fix this so that the app is actually using the correct system culture?

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps it is falling back to the system setting if not specified in the binding. You could use the current thread's culture directly from your converter of course. But now I'm stating the obvious as a workaround ;)

Comment: HAHA!  Indeed, I'd rather know that the app is correctly using the culture rather than force the convertion.  My system is set to en-GB which makes this even stranger to my mind ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d35e0a76-0ab0-44ba-8d8c-892bd2560542/default-cultureinfo-for-wpf) states that you might have to add the following:

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
  typeof(FrameworkElement), 
  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
    XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you created a thread, then the culture info is reset to the default one(for that thread).  I think in .net 4.5 there might be a way to set the default thread cultureinfo.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture.aspx